# Goerli testnet pending transaction taking too long?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, decentralized-applications, etherscan

I'm working on sending transactions from one address to another on the goerli testnet and all transactions so far are not confirming. They have been staying in a pending state: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x056187763bac9adc8696fa0554c26b2f0e8ac48601dd4e5f03a30536d6597bf0

Did I do something wrong? I see the transaction in the etherscan.io/tx, but do I need some sort of callback handler?

Is this because there are not enough miners on the goerli testnet? Is Kovan the best testnet for ethereum dapp/smart contract development where transactions are being confirmed more often?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked transaction offers gas price of `0.000000002` **Gwei** (which is 2 wei). Usual current gas price on the Goerli network is `2` **Gwei** (1 billion times larger).

So it just seems that your sending script incorrectly calculates the decimals for the gas price.

Most miners order transactions by the gas price. So if there were more miners or less pending transactions, there would be a higher probability of this transaction making it to the block. But in the current situation, you need to raise the gas price of your transaction in order to compete with the other pending transactions.

If you want to replace the gas price on this particular transaction, you can send a new one **with the same `nonce`** but higher gas fee.